# How do I find a random BigInteger smaller than another random BigInteger?

Tags: rsa, random, java

How do I Select a random element α ∈ Z∗p? P is a random 1024 bit prime BigInteger.

Here is how I find BigInteger p:

```
Random rand = new Random(new Date().getTime());

BigInteger p= new BigInteger(1024, rand);

while(!p.isProbablePrime(3))
    {
       BigInteger p= new BigInteger(1024, rand);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you selecting a random element within $Z^*_p$?  In crypto, the order of the element is usually critical (depending on the intended use); by selecting a random element, you won't know if the order is prime (or, for that matter, nonsmooth).

Comment: In my experience sampling a random number in some $Z_p$ is a pretty normal thing to do.

Comment: @GuutBoy: indeed, selecting a large random value is quite normal.  However, he specifically mentioned $Z^*_p$, and not all values in that group are the same.  Depending on why he is generating that value, that may be an indication that selecting an arbitrary value may select a value that is weak

Comment: @poncho I needed an element in that set because I was implementing ElGamal's algorithm. This was just a step for it. And I decided to choose 1023 bits random prime instead of a random element which is α ∈ Z∗p. But if you know a function that directly gives a random prime in a given range that will help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is Java. In that case you are actually not picking a 1024 bit prime. You are picking a prime between 0 and $2^{1024}$. Take a look at the API though. There is a static method called some thing like probableprime which will give you a probable prime of a given bit length.

Now to sample a number $a \in Z_p$, you can use the method you used before to sample a random number $r$ between 0 and $2^{1024}$. Then check if $r < p$. If not resamble $r$ until you get an $r < p$. This is called rejection sampling, and should be reasonably efficient in this case.

You should, however, make sure that the randomness used by Java is good enough for your purpose.

Comment: For Java you need either `new SecureRandom()` or possibly - for 1.8 - `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` to get cryptographically secure random values.

Comment: @Guut Boy I could not find a function which gives a 'random' prime of a given bit lenght in java. For selecting $a \in Z_p$, I think there is no function that directly gives a random prime in a given range. If you know any that will help. I'm now choosing 1023 bit prime instead of selecting in this [0,p-1] range.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you probably need in practice is a random k-bit prime (cf. Guut Boy's answer). Maurer published an algorithm of generating such a prime that is "provably" prime (in contrast to one that is obtained with the Miller-Rabin test). I have a Python implementation of Maurer's algorithm available at: http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/